# Where can I find this lib --> libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so

Tags: ros, library, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I am searching for this particular library here:

libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so

I have it on my pc and wanted to transfer my program to another one. I guess I could just copy the file itself, but I am pretty sure this is not how I got it in the first place (it is located at /opt/ros/hydro/lib). So I guess I installed some ros package, which included this library. Does anyone of you nice smart people know which one that might have been? Maybe one of the PR2 packages?

Thanks a lot
Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190555/where-can-i-find-this-lib---%3E-libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-11-23**:
What do we want?
libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so!
When do we want it?
libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are on Ubuntu / Debian / any distro with `dpkg`:

```
user@machine:~$ dpkg -S libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser
ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-08-19**:
Alright, thanks, I guess it was always there, but not working the same way as on my other pc -->everytime I try to access the plugin for the hokuyo this way my node crashes :(
But thanks again,
Marcus

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-19**:
Sounds like that is an issue for another question. This one is answered then?

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-08-19**:
Yup, this question was answered and I solved my other problem by choosing another lib (dunno why, but now it works). Anyways, thanks again and I flagged your response as an answer :)